# Ajax code is not getting executed

Tags: ajax

I am trying to create a user and register by calling the WebAPI. Below is the code. But the following code is not getting called. Please kindly help.

Thanks and Regards,
Abhijit

Following is the code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/account/register',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        Email: $('#txtEmail').val(),
        Password: $('#txtPassword').val(),
        ConfirmPassword: $('#txtConfirmPassword').val(),
    },
    success: function () {
        $('#successModal').modal('show');
    },
    error: function (jqXHR) {
        $('#divErrorText').text(jqXHR.resposeText);
        $('#divError').show('fade');
    }

});
```

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. It does not show any error.. Its just that it does not execute the code.

Comment: Try adding some `console.log` calls in order to make sure of the execution flow, add them at the level of the calling function and inside the `success` and `error` callbacks of the ajax call and show us the results.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your suggestions and help! Using console.log I could figure out the issue and it was a very trivial one. Thanks again.